# Can I connect a database with MySQL if I only have the hyperlink of the Tableau server and the username and password for that?

Tags: mysql, tableau-api

So, there is a Tableau workbook/database that I can access via a hyperlink (http://...) and input of username and password. I can access the Tableau workbook/database with  browser and Tableau desktop. I would like to know a way to connect the database using MySQL.

Comment: *I would like to know a way to connect the database using MySQL.* All the data which you know is not relative to MySQL. Short answer - no.

Comment: I was thinking that normally we connect a database in MySQL with IP address and port. There might be a way to connect it using the hyperlink.

Comment: You access web-server. It access some script server (PHP for example) which may posess on another host with another IP (even private IP not accessible from Internet) and maybe using another credentials. Script server access MySQL which may posess on the third host with third IP (which may be grey too) and using third (MySQL-specific) credentials. So in general no way to access MySQL directly.

Comment: Thank you for your response so far @Akina. But when I use Tableau server to access the web-server, or use Tableau desktop, I can click into the database and read and download the data. This is all I need, but I prefer to do it in MySQL, since I can download the data to my local server / local drive and have the read and write authority. (I suppose if I can do it using Tableau Desktop, I do not need additional credentials if I want to perform the same function in MySQL.)

Comment: I think the best way is to ask this question to the support service. They know exactly whether it is possible or not, and if it is possible, they will tell you exactly how to do it, so as not to harm.

Comment: Now I get what you mean when you say I might need additional credentials for accessing the rawer data - I currently have the right to access the "table" generated from one or more sources but do not have the right to access those sources. Thank you for your time and advice!